# What will happen when I scroll up and down UITableView because it's related to a bug I am trying to figure it out

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avaudioplayer

I want to know what will happen when I scroll UITableView up and down. Because I am facing a bug related to this. The situation is like this, when I click a button, the cell's AVAudioPlayer will play a audio url, and when I scroll table view up and down, sometimes the view will freeze. I don't know what's caused this. So I am trying to figure out.

Comment: And we don't know without any piece of code.

Comment: Add some code. It seems that your AVAudioPlayer is being allocated everytime you scrolls the table.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:):

> For performance reasons, a table view’s data source should generally
>   reuse UITableViewCell objects when it assigns cells to rows in its
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. A table view maintains a
>   queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has
>   marked for reuse. Call this method from your data source object when
>   asked to provide a new cell for the table view. This method dequeues
>   an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the
>   class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available
>   for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method
>   returns nil.

That means:

When cell A disappears and cell B appears and they have the same identifier, UIKit will reuse cell A and it will be returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` call.
If there is no cell to reuse - they will create a new one.

You can use [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) method to handle/prepare a cell for reuse.

If you would like to play audio with `AVAudioPlayer`, define a property in your `UITableViewController`. Do not create an `AVAudioPlayer` object for each cell.